# using alter to add column with specific definition

Tags: sql, oracle, alter

how do i add a column to an existing table with a given definition. For example i have a table called employee with column called hire_date. Now using alter and **only** alter, i want to add a column called tenure which contains the difference between (hire_date and 14-JULY-2012). this is what ive tried

```
alter table employee add(tenure numeric(10) where tenure=(select to_date(
'14-JULY-2012')-HIRE_DATE from employee));
```

Comment: you are try anything?? if yes then please put it here..

Comment: Sounds like a virtual column to me. What Oracle version are you using?

Comment: dont want to use virtual column, that i can do using case. i want this column to be added permanently. my version is 11.0.2.0.2 and im using sql plus

Comment: It's a strange and suspect design that involves a magic date (14-JULY-2012). What is the significance of that particular date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from 11g, this should work:

```
ALTER TABLE employee 
 ADD tenure GENERATED ALWAYS 
   AS (TO_DATE('20120714','YYYYMMDD') - hire_date) VIRTUAL
```

Comment: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Comment: Try `TO_DATE('20120714','YYYYMMDD') `

Comment: im an sql newbie but dont we have to give a type to the added column?

Comment: The type can be derived from the function used.

Comment: yes @Thilo u r right. just one thing though, how can i get the difference in years while considering for leap years and all.

Comment: That's a whole different question.

Comment: hey thilo remove the virtual part . i want the column to be permanent

Comment: The GENERATED ALWAYS and VIRTUAL keywords are provided for clarity only. It does the exact same thing with or without.

Comment: @Thilo- I was trying same thing with `Default` keyword.. but I failed to do so.

with `Generated Always` we can not change the value, if we want in future to change value for some rows..

is there possibility / query where we can add these two functionality.. means just Defaulting with any column value (or expression referring any column value) and later on we can change according to condition ...

Answer (score 1):

Since the new column can be derived from an existing column, I would not add it to the table.  It's hard work to keep a derived column consistent, and there are better alternatives.

Instead, you could create a view that adds the column:

```
create view ViewName as
select  hire_date
,       hire_date - TO_DATE('20120714','YYYYMMDD') as DaysSinceJuly14th
,       ... other columns ...
from    employees
```

Or you could do the calculation on the fly in any select statement:

```
select  hire_date - TO_DATE('20120714','YYYYMMDD') as DaysSinceJuly14th
from    employees
where   name = 'Jones'
```

Comment: erm.. it has to be done using only alter. Sry, but my boss wont let me use any other command :(

Comment: That is a requirement that makes no sense at all.